How to solve npm install error 'npm ERR! code 1'
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hasin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
npm ERR! Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
npm ERR! [>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! ^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0KDownloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! ^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0KDownloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded python-2.7.15.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\hasin\.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.15.amd64.msi.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0KDownloading vs_BuildTools.exe
npm ERR! [>                                            ] 0.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! ^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0KDownloading vs_BuildTools.exe
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! ^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0K^[[1A^[[1000D^[[0KDownloading vs_BuildTools.exe
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% (0 B/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to C:\Users\hasin\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Starting installation...
npm ERR! Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor
npm ERR!     at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
npm ERR!     at Object.removePath (C:\Users\hasin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\utils\remove-path.js:11:12)
npm ERR!     at Object.install (C:\Users\hasin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\install\index.js:29:19)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\hasin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\start.js:17:19
npm ERR!     at Object.download (C:\Users\hasin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\download.js:35:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR!     at async Object.aquireInstallers (C:\Users\hasin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\aquire-installers.js:32:13) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_INVALID_OBJECT_DEFINE_PROPERTY'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! windows-build-tools will now exit.
npm ERR! (node:10928) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\hasin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-07T14_05_09_831Z-debug-0.log

following code is what I have tried initially and then got the above error.
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools


Are you sure you need this? Did you read the package description? https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools
